# Emacs cperl mode: disabling insertion of "if" etc

Tags: perl, emacs, cperl-mode

I've been using cperl-mode in Emacs for some time. On a new system, I've been getting a problematic behaviour: when I type something like "if", Emacs expands it into a full-blown statement, so it'll automatically give me

```
if () {
}
```

This is really distracting. Setting cperl-electric-keywords to nil doesn't change this behaviour. I already have cperl-hairy set to nil.

I see there was discussion of this on Perl Monks here http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=864654 , and it does work, as suggested there, to say cperl-toggle-abbrev, or to use the menu Perl -> Toggle -> Electric Keywords. But I want this behaviour to be permanent, and putting (setq cperl-electric-keywords nil) into my .emacs doesn't work.

How can I modify my .emacs to handle this?

Comment: Not familiar with these functions/variables, but can you just put `(cperl-toggle-abbrev)` in your .emacs file?  If that function works interactively, you should be able to put it in your .emacs.  Might need an arg after the function name, if it requires one.

Comment: Please try to reproduce this in `emacs -Q`. It sounds like a configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. When I launch with emacs -Q, the behaviour does not occur. However, to reiterate, in my usual setup, even when cperl-electric-keywords is nil, I still see the behaviour. That is, it doesn't seem to be just an issue with my configuration files--I can be in a file in cperl-mode, check the value of cperl-electric-keywords, see that it's nil, and type "if ", and still get the entire framework pop up. I don't know the difference between this, and what happens under emacs -Q. Thanks.